# Are these throughput numbers typical for an SSD?

Tags: performance, ssd

```
Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await  svctm  %util
sdb           19722.20   170.80 7141.60   27.80 114246.40   788.80    32.09    52.25    7.19   0.14 100.00
sda               4.40     6.80  331.00   43.00  1950.40   199.20    11.50     0.42    1.12   0.14   5.36
sdc            3357.60   105.00 5181.80   51.80 35856.80   627.20    13.94    13.00    2.48   0.19  98.20
sdd              48.80    88.00  902.00  128.00  5916.80   864.00    13.17     0.95    0.93   0.10  10.56
```

Basically SSD utilization reach 100% for reading 114MB/s data.

What's typical speed of SSD anyway?

Comment: Which command did you use to produce this output? iostat? Please include this info in your question.

Comment: appears to be `iostat -dkx` output.

Comment: iostat -xk 5. I am using 114mb /s. If that's the case it seems normal.

Comment: I want to know whether 114MB /s for SSD is normal or not

Answer (score 1):

The Arch Linux wiki has a good SSD benchmarking page. The best solution to test reading and writing speed is to use dd:

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SSD_Benchmarking#Using_dd

Write speed:

```
$ cd /path/to/SSD
$ dd if=/dev/zero of=tempfile bs=1M count=1024 conv=fdatasync,notrunc
1024+0 records in
1024+0 records out
w bytes (x GB) copied, y s, z MB/s
```

Read speed:

```
# echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
$ dd if=tempfile of=/dev/null bs=1M count=1024
1024+0 records in
1024+0 records out
w bytes (x GB) copied, y s, z MB/s
```

Performance results depends a lot in your disk, as you can see in https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SSD_Benchmarking#Table

#### Performance Data

If you take a look at the table from the URL above you'll notice the following:

```
Vendor    Model             Cap [GB]   Write [MB/sec]  Read [MB/sec]  Re-Read [MB/sec] 
-----     -----             --------   --------------  -------------  ----------------
Crucial   C300              128        138             372            6500
...
CZ        Vertex 3          120        245             225            4600
OCZ       Vertex Turbo      30         49              115            2600
OCZ       Vertex 2          240        852?            241            3400
OCZ       Vertex 3          120        377             291            10300            
OCZ       Agility 3         120        445             455            8200
Samsung   MMCQE28GFMUP-MVA  128        45              99             2300             
Samsung   470               64         188             204            1000
...
```

You're Read score of 114 MB/s puts you at the bottom of of the list with respect to the other SSD cards in the table (see the `Read [MB/sec]` column).

Comment: It's not realy answer.

Comment: @MohsenPahlevanzadeh - sure this is. It shows how to simulate load to the SSD and also provides tables of similar SSDs with their performance data.

Comment: @JimThio - see updates that I made to this answer. I've included some of the scores from the link that fclad provided in the answer, and commented on where your 114MB/s ranks.